# TweepError: bad handshake 'osrandom_rand_bytes'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tweepy

I have been working with tweepy and raspberry pi (3b) units for some time now, and I decided to reflash/repurpose my raspberry pi zero (w/ camera) to create a monitoring twitter bot. I have used tweepy on my pi 3B to gather tweets, and even do some tweet automation.

But, for some reason, I have been getting the following error when I try to execute a simple test tweet script on my pi zero.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_tweet.py", line 15, in <module>
    api.update_status("successful!")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 194, in update_status
    )(post_data=post_data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 192, in execute
    six.reraise(TweepError, TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 190, in execute
    proxies=self.api.proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: ("bad handshake: Error([('', 'osrandom_rand_bytes', 'getrandom() initialization failed.')],)",)
```

here's my python code in test_tweet.py

```
import tweepy

def tweepy_creds():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("conskeyhere", "conssecret")
    auth.set_access_token("accesstoken", "accesstokensecret")
    return tweepy.API(auth)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = tweepy_creds()
    api.update_status("successful!")
```

it's the first time I encountered such an error.

/ogs

Comment: what happens if you place `time.sleep(120)` as the first line in the script? It may be related to the problem [discussed here](https://lwn.net/Articles/693189/).

Comment: @JamesKPolk hello, i tried using time.sleep(300) (and even time.sleep(600) -- 10 minutes!). but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I will, however try out installing rng-tools as stated in the link... will post an update in a while.

Comment: thanks! @JamesKPolk i did an apt-get install rng-tools and it worked.